# How to hand an object from backend to frontend

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I try to create a Web App. Therefor I have to pass an Object from the backend to the HTML-Script. I tried a lot of possibilites but nothing worked.

**Backend**

```
function searchMain (allSeaVal) {

   var headCon = DbSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, DbSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
   var bodyCon = DbSheet.getRange(valRow, typesCol, 1, DbSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

   var Con = {
       headline: headCon, 
       values:   bodyCon
      };
             
     var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page_js');
     tmp.Con = Con.map(function(r){ return r; });
       return tmp.evaluate();
 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script>
    function searchValues() {
      var allSeaVal = {};

      allSeaVal.seaType = document.getElementById('valSearchTyp').value;
      allSeaVal.seaVal = document.getElementById('HSearchVal').value;
       
      
      google.script.run.searchMain(allSeaVal); 

      Logger.log(Con);
   }
<script/>
```

I want to use the information in "Con" in the Website. The script-code is stored in the file "page_js.
I don´t know why but I can´t pass the information into the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html interface you have to use the success and failure handler in your google.script.run.

Code will looks like

```
  google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(
          function(msg) {
            // Respond to success conditions here.
            console.log('Execution successful.');
          })
        .withFailureHandler(
          function(msg) {
            // Respond to failure conditions here.
            console.log('Execution failed: ' + msg, 'error');
          })
        .searchMain(allSeaVal);
```

Do not hesitate to check the documentation : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Stéphane

Comment: Thank you.  This helped a lot. 
It seems that the searchMain () function isn´t working, but I think that it will be more easy to find my mistake with the FailureHandler()

Comment: I did not check this function true, just put the code for frontend and backend communication.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with your help. Thank you so much. I struggled with this many days.
My solution is the code below.

**Backend**

```
function searchMain (allSeaVal) {

 var typesCol = searchTypesCol(allSeaVal.seaType);
 var valRow = searchRow(allSeaVal.seaVal, typesCol);

   var headCon = DbSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, DbSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
   var bodyCon = DbSheet.getRange(valRow, typesCol, 1, DbSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

   var Con = {
       headline: headCon, 
       values:   bodyCon
      };

     return Con;

}
```

**HTML**

```
function searchValues() {
      var allSeaVal = {};

      allSeaVal.seaType = document.getElementById('valSearchTyp').value;
      allSeaVal.seaVal = document.getElementById('HSearchVal').value;


      google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(
                 function(Con) {
                   console.log(Con + 'success');

                 })
            .withFailureHandler(
              function(Con) {
                  console.log(Con + 'failure');
                })
            .searchMain(allSeaVal);

   }
```